# Apex method not executing when called from LWC component

Tags: apex, lwc

I have written simple logic to call the apex method at the time of initialization of page load and in return I have returned the boolean value from the apex but the Apex method is itself not getting invoked from LWC
can anyone please guide me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuRCb.png)

COde-

Answer (score 0):

You've only imported the apex method.

You now need to run it imperatively in your connectedCallback hook.

For example:

```
connectedCallback() {
 //call BeforeInsert2 here 
}
```

See these articles:

1. https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/12/13/connectedcallback-in-lightning-web-component/
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative

Please mark this answer as correct if it helped you. Also, I recommend using https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ for quicker responses.